# Is it possible to programmatically check the version of an app available on the playstore?

Tags: android

I want to implement force update feature in my app which means,  if any upgrade is available in playstore the user need to upgrade the app to its latest version thats the concept.

For this, i need to know how can we check the version of an app available in playstore.

And one other thing is when the user clicks the upgrade button the app page in playstore should show update instead of install.

Answer (score 0):

For forcing the user to upgrade the app you can use remote config feature provided in FCM for disabling the app remotely.

Also check this link for getting app data from playstore. https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/